# Show message box after click event

Tags: c#, click, messagebox, infopath

I'm writing custom code behind an InfoPath form that does several things, and I want a message box to pop up when everything's done that says "Export Done. Click OK to continue." The timing on the message box isn't working correctly, however. Here's the details:

The code below is the Clicked event for the "Export" button on the form. It does two things - exports a view of the form to a PDF file, then copies form data to a SharePoint list via web service.

```
public void CTRL_PDF_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Write your code here.
            bool exportDone = false;

            //Declare variables
            string fileName;
            string fileLocation;
            XPathNavigator nameNode;
            XPathNavigator folderNode;
            XPathNavigator timeNode;
            //Set the values for each variable
            nameNode = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:PDFName", NamespaceManager);
            folderNode = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:FolderLocation", NamespaceManager);
            fileName = nameNode.Value;
            fileLocation = folderNode.Value;


            //Do the work -- switch to the PDF view then export it as a PDF file.
            Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.View currentView = this.CurrentView;
            this.CurrentView.Export(@fileLocation + fileName + ".pdf", ExportFormat.Pdf);


            //Now set up the values for SharePoint
            string jobID = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:PostID", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string formPT = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Total_PT", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string formBC = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Total_BC", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string formSRS = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Total_SRS", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string srsChoice = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SRSOption", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string engName = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Engineer/my:Engineer_Company", NamespaceManager).Value;


            // Now update the list item in SharePoint
            XPathNavigator batch = DataSources["Post CAML"].CreateNavigator();
            batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='ID']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(jobID);
            batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='EstimatedFeet']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(formPT);
            batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='BCEstFT']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(formBC);
            //batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='SRSEst']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(formSRS);
            batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='SRS']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(srsChoice);
            batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='Engineer']", NamespaceManager).SetValue(engName);

            string xmlPTEst = batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='EstimatedFeet']", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string xmlBCEst = batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='BCEstFT']", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string xmlSRSEst = batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='SRSEst']", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string xmlSRSVal = batch.SelectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='SRS']", NamespaceManager).Value;

            WebServiceConnection wc = (WebServiceConnection)this.DataConnections["Web Service Submit"];

            wc.Execute();

            exportDone = true;

            if (exportDone == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Export Done. Click OK to continue.");
            }

            // End your code here.
        }
```

The problem I'm running into is that the messagebox shows up as soon as the button is clicked, behind the export progress bar. When the progress bar completes after a second or two, both it and the message box disappear. Here's a screenshot of what I see for those two seconds:

[image]

**How can I make the message box pop up AFTER the Clicked Event is finished processing everything?**

---

**EDIT:** I updated the code to use a boolean variable (exportDone) that starts out false and gets set to true after the web service execution. This did not resolve the issue, however.

Comment: All the code above `MessageBox.Show` runs before the message box is shown, so I'm not sure what the question is? Have you stepped through this with the debugger to determine what is happening?

Comment: @RonBeyer - yes, it's not showing any errors. From a user experience, the message box shows up, but then goes away without having to click OK. I'm stumped.

Comment: What about checking `DialogResult`?

`if (MessageBox.Show("Content", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK) { }`